# jQuery file upload in IE9 works only partly (with plugin jQuery File Upload)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

The central aims of this upload with this plugin:

- Upload up to 3 files (images) through 3 different input fields, without page reload.
- Do this together with other form data, that is not connected to a single file.
- Do it when creating and when editing a content item (in this case a category).

I tested the IE9 in a VM with Windows 7. In Firefox, Chrome and Edge there is no problem.

The problem in IE9 is:
The upload does not work, when only 1 file is uploaded and this file is not the last file (so when I removed the third file input field, the upload through the second file input field worked).
There is no problem, when at least 2 files are uploaded together.

The libraries and plugins I use are:

- jquery 1.12.1 (also used versions down to 1.8.3-)
- jquery-ui 1.11.4 (also used a version 1.9.2)
- jQuery-File-Upload 9.12.1 (also used versions down to 8.1.0):

  - jquery.iframe-transport.js
  - jquery.fileupload.js

The configuration of the plugin:

```
file_upload = form.fileupload({replaceFileInput: false}, {
    //file_upload = form.fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        singleFileUploads: false,
        autoUpload: false,

        add: function(e,data){
            uploadCategoryWithImage = true;
            filesList.push(data.files[0]);
            paramNames.push(data.paramName);
        },

        done: function(e, data) {
            switch (uploadContext) {
                case 'update':
                    updateCategoryDone(node, form, data.result, data);
                    break;
                case 'create':
                    storeNewCategoryDone(node, form, data.result)
                    break;
                case 'createLevel1':
                    storeNewCategoryLevel1Done(form, data.result);
            }
        },

        fail: function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            console.log('prepareCategoryFileUploads fail [jqXHR, textStatus]: ', [jqXHR, textStatus]);
        }

    });
```

Used after click of submit button of form:

```
file_upload.fileupload('send', {files:filesList, paramName: paramNames});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem is that when only one of the 3 input fields have a file to upload, in the form created in jquery.iframe-transport.js ALL input fields of type "file" (instead of only one) have in the name attribute the name of the input field that really has a file to submit.

So for IE9, or generally for browsers without window.FileReader, for paramName I now give an array with ALL names of input fields of type "file". This can not be used in newer browsers, so this change really must be limited to browsers without support for window.FileReader.

Now after form submit a code like this is used:

```
if (!window.FileReader) {
    paramNames = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
}
file_upload.fileupload('send', {files:filesList, paramName: paramNames});
```